# Should Azure Face API's Large Face List be trained every time a new face is added to it?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I use Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API for a face recognition project, where users keep adding faces over a period of time. Previously, the faces were stored in a "Face List". I am shifting the faces to a "Large Face List" now. However, it requires a training call, which "Face Lists" did not require.

I am unable to find any documentation that mentions if

- we have to train it once? or
- train it every time a face is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not stated in the [REST documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/face/largefacelist) for Face API but it is stated in the [actual documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/how-to-use-large-scale) of the Face API at the very beginning.

> To enable Face search performance for Identification and FindSimilar
>   in large scale, introduce a Train operation to preprocess the
>   LargeFaceList and LargePersonGroup. The training time varies from
>   seconds to about half an hour based on the actual capacity. During the
>   training period, it's possible to perform Identification and
>   FindSimilar if a successful training operating was done before. The
>   drawback is that the new added persons and faces don't appear in the
>   result until a new post migration to large-scale training is
>   completed.

Which means you need to train it every time there is an addition to the faces, as `LargeFaceList` is meant for large-scale use (with up to 1,000,000 faces), thus, if you don't require that capacity, then you might want to go with `FaceList` (with up to 1,000 faces) since it doesn't require training every time.

Comment: If I have LargePersonGroup with 50000 Person with 4 faces each and for them Group is already trained , now if I add 5 new person with 4 faces each to this large person group. How much time will it take to train this group again ? will it be for 5 persons only (that might be few seconds) OR will it be for 50005 persons ?

Comment: It will train for all, that is why it would be a good idea to use standalone training as can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/how-to-use-large-scale#step-33-standalone-training) and also more insights can be found in the same link.